# Unable to open already existing SoapUI project

Tags: soapui

I've been given a basic SoapUI project to run some tests against a mock server. When I import the project into SoapUI, it is greyed out and only gives me an option to reload the project.

When I load up the XML file for the project, it seems to be invalid, but it should still work according to the documentation.

Is there something in the XML I should look out for when importing, or is there a different way to import SoapUI projects other than using the "Import" function?

Answer (score 3):

I too faced this problem. The below steps helped me to resolve it:

1. Click on new Project Tab in SoapUI and create a New Empty Project with default parameters.
2. Then Right click and choose save project as option, and save it in XML file format.
3. Then copy entire content of your Old XML projects (which you're not able to open because it is greyed out) and paste it into the XML file saved in step 2 (overwriting all its previous content).
4. Save the file.
5. Then import your project with this updated XML file (as its having content of your previous project only, so entire previous project would be restored).

I don't know the logic behind this but this thing worked for me, hence sharing here for everyone's benefit!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to check:

- Check the soapUI, error logs, and other log files (tabs across the bottom of the screen). They're usually very informative.
- Is the project or test case disabled? Check the right-click context menu.
- Is the project a single XML file or a series of folders? If it's the latter then it's a composite project and it'll only work in Pro versions of the product.
- Has the project been checked out of a version control system like Subversion or Git? I've had some IDE's/VCS's 'prettify' the XML and cause problems, or often there's an unresolved merge conflict that someone has left behind.

As a last resort, look through the project file using a text editor. Is it valid XML; is there a junk character in a saved message payload?

Comment: Thanks for all the good tips. I am getting a lot of error when importing the project, mainly with invalid XML. It is a single XML file. The XML contains [CDATA] elements, which seem to make the XML invalid, but I'm not sure if they should be removed. It has not been checked out of a version control system.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML files were packaged into a zip file, there could be artifacts introduced.  Look for XML of the form:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<!-- content -->
=======
<!-- duplicated content -->
>>>>>>>
```

and remove everything except for the first {content} section.  Also, be sure to keep any trailing  tags after the ">>>>>>".

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a simular problem.

I couldnt even start SoapUI anymore. I found out that the reason was one of the SoapUI projects in my workspace. I removed the project from my workspace-file so I could start SoapUI again.

The project had MQTT teststeps in it. I used an editor to remove the teststeps from the project file. Then I was able to open the project file again.

```
      <con:testStep type="MQTTPublishTestStep" name="Publish using MQTT"/>
      <con:testStep type="MQTTDropConnectionTestStep" name="Drop MQTT Connection"/>
      <con:testStep type="MQTTReceiveTestStep" name="Receive MQTT Message"/>
```